# Getting viewParam in POST

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

Consider the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

    <f:metadata>
        <o:viewParam name="selected" value="#{testBacking.selected}" >
        </o:viewParam>
    </f:metadata>

    <h:head>
        <title>
            title
        </title>

    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <o:form includeViewParams="true">
            <h:commandButton action="#{testBacking.go()}" value="go">
                <f:ajax execute="@all" render="@all"/>
            </h:commandButton>
        </o:form>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

The action method:

```
public void go() {
    System.out.println("go() is called");

    Collection<UIViewParameter> viewParams = ViewMetadata.getViewParameters(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot());

    for (UIViewParameter viewParam : viewParams) {
        System.out.println(viewParam.getName() +" = "+ viewParam.getValue());
    }
}
```

The action method returns correct viewParam name, but the value always null. If this is the intended behaviour, how `<o:form includeViewParams="true">` helps in practical usage?

I am using Mojarra 2.1.12 and Omnifaces 1.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bean is apparently request scoped. The `<o:viewParam>` is intented to be used in combination with **view scoped** beans only because it prevents the model being converted/validated/updated again and again on every postback to the *same* view even though it was *already* done during the initial request and is *still* there as property of the view scoped bean. This improves overall performance when the model is being bound to an expensive converter which performs the job based on DB calls. The [showcase example](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/viewParam) also shows this clearly.

To achieve this, the `<o:viewParam>` basically skips this model conversion/validation/update job during any postback. A request scoped bean is however newly created on every request and the initial model value is thus lost on every postback and due to the design of `<o:viewParam>` not being set at all.

You can solve this by placing the bean in the view scope, or by just using the standard `<f:viewParam>` instead.

As to the `<o:form includeViewParams="true">`, this is only useful on synchronous postbacks. If you remove the `<f:ajax>` then you'll see how it's useful. Without `includeViewParams="true"` the URL becomes the one without the view parameter, i.e. without `?selected=somevalue` and it becomes thus unbookmarkable. This has no strict relationship with `<o:viewParam>`, it works as good in combination with `<f:viewParam>`.

Comment: Thanks very much and thanks for offering the fantastic Omnifaces to the JSF community.

Comment: You're welcome :) There's by the way a `Faces.getViewParameters()` shortcut for getting all view parameters.